# Dugger's theorem for enriched model categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

We know that a [combinatorial model category has a small presentation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/combinatorial+model+category#DuggerTheorem).

Is an enriched version of this theorem known? The closest I could find is: [Guillou, May - Enriched model categories and presheaf categories (2011)](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/PAPERS/VmodPLAIN2018%20copy.pdf), but (as far as I understand) it discusses a narrower question (sufficient conditions for an enriched model category to be Quillen equivalent to a presheaf category with the projective model structure).

Comment: This is supposed to be in HTT Appendix A.3, but looking at it now I think you'll have to piece it together from the diagram category part + the localization part.

Comment: See also the more general Conjecture 1.10 in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04679v2; as far as I know, it has not been resolved.

Comment: @ArshakAivazian Could you please state precisely what you mean by "an enriched version of this theorem"? Depending on what would satisfy you, I might be able to write an answer.